# New fragment from fragment after imageView click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, toolbar

i'm trying to call a fragment from an another, but when i call it, the toolbar still with the same name, how to reload it ?

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView actualites = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.thirdBlock);
    actualites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new Actualites();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.accueil, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

My Toolbar is changed on an another class activity (with menu):

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Accueil();
            title = getString(R.string.title_accueil);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new NosOffres();
            title = getString(R.string.title_nosoffres);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ContactezNous();
            title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Actualites();
            title = getString(R.string.title_actu);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new MentionsLegales();
            title = getString(R.string.title_mentions);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        TextView titlet;
        titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
        titlet.setText(title);
        titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
    }
}
```

Thanks !! I juste need to get back the Toolbar name !

I just tried:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new Actualites();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.accueil, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        String title = getString(R.string.title_actu);
        TextView titlet;
        titlet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
        titlet.setText(title);
        titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
    }
```

errors:

```
05-26 08:19:56.859  28432-28432/package E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at package.Accueil$1.onClick(Accueil.java:46)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity create a *setTitle(String title)* method and in each fragment do:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).setTitle(newTitle)
```

for example, in onResume() method of Fragment

For more information about communicating with fragments see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: I tryed but dont working, @strike have found the solution, but thanks :)

Comment: In activity create method setTitle, in which you do titlet.setText(title); Each activity itself must be responsible for their appearance. It's a bad practise to invoke activity's view directly from a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fragment try to access Acitivty View like this.

```
TextView textView =(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
 textView.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can update title and change fragment by two ways:

(I) Inside `onClickListener()` of your fragment
Replace your fragment using activity fragment manager that is `getActivity.getFragmentmanager()` and use your container id and than you can notify your title by creating some method inside your activity and access that using `(Activityname)getActivity().methodName()`.

(II) In my opinion this is best way:

Call your activity by getActivity() and call your displayView(pos) method directly.

```
((XYZ)getActivity()).displayView(3);
```

And it'll change your fragment and title as well.

Please let me know in case i misunderstood your question and answer is not what you expecting.